# A volatile class member in C++

Tags: c++, volatile

I know that you can add 'volatile' keyword to a method, but can you do the same with a class attribute in C++?

E.g.

```
class PCB {
public:
static volatile PCB* running;
...
};
```

Comment: Sure, that's valid syntax. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes you can. Just keep in mind it doesn't have the same semantic in Java because volatile in C++ doesn't imply memory barriers.

Comment: You can put it wherever you can put `const`.

Comment: Did you try compiling it with `volatile` there? That would have answered your question.

Comment: Just because something compiles on one compiler, doesn't make the syntax valid (... although, in this case it is). Most compilers have some c++ extensions, that allow you to compile programs that would be considered ill-formed in others.

Answer (score 2):

`volatile` is a cv-qualifier, which is valid within any type specifier. `static` is a storage specifier, but in no way disqualifies the type to be cv-qualified as well.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

> cv (const and volatile) type qualifiers
>   Appear in any type specifier, including decl-specifier-seq of
>   declaration grammar, to specify constness or volatility of the object
>   being declared or of the type being named.